# Creating an interface in Laravel, I cannot sub a child class for its parent in a function

Tags: php, laravel, inheritance

So I have a type of custom form request, for example MakeTeaRequest or MakeCoffeeRequest. This custom form request extends MakeDrinkRequest.

In a new interface I am creating, I would like to define a function which can take any child of MakeDrinkRequest, so I have done the following:

```
Interface DrinkControllerInterface
{

    public function store(MakeDrinkRequest $request);
    ...
```

However, in my class which implements DrinkControllerInterface, when I am writing the store function, I get the following error in my IDE:

`public function store(MakeTeaRequest $request)`

> Declaration must be compatible with DrinkControllerInterface->store(request: \App\Http\Requests\MakeDrinkRequest)

Am I going about this the wrong way from a design perspective? Or is there something else that I can do to allow for any child of that class to be subbed for the parent class?

Comment: Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.variance.php You can only accept *more general* or return *more specific*.

Comment: Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_method_parameter_type

Comment: @Yoshi okay I see, thanks for your help there!